# Calculate if value is closer to the highest or the lowest value

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have three numbers. Highest, lowest and an average.

For example:

```
Highest: 1 409 998
Lowest: 1 010 189
Avg: 1 309 998
```

I need a metric/KPI where I can indicate if the avg value is closer to the highest value. Or how much in percentage the avg value is closer to the highest value.

In this example if the avg was the same as the highest (1 409 998) then it would be 100%. If the avg would be the same as the lowest (1 010 189) it would be 0%. If the avg is right in the middle then it would be 50%.

Comment: Of course, the average of two numbers is always 50%.

Comment: ...............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using this formula:

```
percent = 100 * (average - lowest) / (highest - lowest)
```